# Can moviepy handle aiff audio?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, moviepy, aiff

I have a python script that pulls random audio clips from a hard drive. It finds wav and mp3 files and moviepy deals with them fine. When I added the aiff extensions to the search query I get this from moviepy...

`codec = extensions_dict[ext[1:]]['codec'][0] KeyError: "'aiff'"`

Does anyone know if moviepy specifically does not handle aiff audio?
Could there be a simple way to add aiff handling to moviepy?

Comment: You need to pass a codec name to moviepy as there isn’t one in its default codex lookup dict.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the head's up Tom. In case this can help someone else, here's what is working for me now.

```
for clip, title in audioClips.items(): #Iterate by key & value through the dictionary
    #print(f"The title is {title}.")
    if title.endswith('.aif') or title.endswith('aiff'):
        clip.write_audiofile(dirpath+str(title),codec='pcm_s16le')
    else:
        clip.write_audiofile(dirpath+str(title))
    clip.close()
```